# How to pass multi-valued arguments containing commas to a property in dotnet command line tool?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, dotnet-test, coverlet

I want to run a command that includes this:

`dotnet test /p:Exclude=\"*Test*,*Requirement*\"`

The above is not the full command, but it's enough to provoke the parsing error. I am using the Coverlet NuGet package in my C# project and I want to exclude all projects that match those names.

I've read both [here](https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet/blob/master/Documentation/MSBuildIntegration.md) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2999) that enclosing the arguments in \"escaped quotes\" should do it, but it doesn't work. I get:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1006: Property is not valid.
Switch: *Requirement*\
```

Using regular unescaped quotes gives the same error message:

`dotnet test /p:Exclude="*Test*,*Requirement*"`

Escaping the comma gives the same error message:

`dotnet test /p:Exclude=*Test*\,*Requirement*`

**NOTE**: The above example might not be correct Coverlet syntax. That's irrelevant for now. I just want to be able to pass a comma-separated list of values to one parameter. As it stands, dotnet rejects my syntax long before it reaches Coverlet.

I am running the commands from PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that in PowerShell, `%2c` gets interpreted as a comma. So I can type this:

`dotnet test /p:Exclude=*Test*%2c*Requirement*`

Answer (score 0):

Or try this it will exclude any project that starts with ProjectX and any project that has Test in it.

```
dotnet test /p:Exclude=\"[ProjectX.*]*,[*Test*]*\"
```